# What can I use to have aerial imaging delivered via slippy URL format

Tags: imagery, web-service, aerial-photography, slippy

We have been given a license to aerial imaging from a local supplier. They are available in: 
* 1km x 1km tiles in MGA coordinates in both TIFF and ECW file format
* Mosaiced blocks in MGA coordinates in ECW file format.

Our goal is to have these available on an iPad using the Motion-X GPS HD Application and its custom map & map download features.

However we would need to take these tiles and deliver them from a webserver or tileserver(?) in the slippy URL format (eg: http://.../Z/X/Y.png)

Looking for advise on a webserver or tileserver or whatever setup and/or maybe even some off the shelf software package/server software that will allow us to do this easily.

We do have some other maps & charts provided to us as well but they are in GeoTiff format.

Wondering if you could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you looked at using GDAL's gdal2tiles utility for creating the tiles?

Answer (score 1):

The answers given so far are all valid.  However, there are yet more options. A very popular option would be [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/). Geoserver will make all the tiles at the various zoom levels.  You can seed the cache and/or have users seed the cache through their requests.

Proprietary solutions include ArcServer, which is expensive but very capable.

Other options could include [TileCache](http://tilecache.org/) possibly with [TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/) if required.  Also [mod_tile](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mod_tile) possibly with Mapnik as part of the rendering toolchain (discussed in the link).

In my opinion, Geoserver is possibly one of the simplest 'all-in' solutions without having to hand-off the rendering or caching.  It is compliant with the slippy map request but can be used with the simpler leaflet/OpenLayers style WMS requests.

Answer (score 0):

QGis has the QTiles plugin, see https://github.com/nextgis/QTiles , which can batch create the tiles you need.

Note: this will generate all tiles for the specified zoom levels. This will use quite some storage space, if you want them at >=z19.

These can then be simply put on a webserver. Any webserver will to. Just point your client to the tiles URL/directory.

You'll have to add all your files to a qgis project, and then use the QTiles plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Global Mapper is another option. Open the TIFF or ECW in Global Mapper then use the Export/Web Format and choose TMS Tiles. You can then upload the resultant folder to your web server. We use AWS to store tiles. Then add the resultant URL to Motion X. You could also look at using Galileo Offline Maps and creating an MBTiles file in Global Mapper then you can upload directly to the device and have complete offline access.